# Mysql very strange behavior

Tags: mysql

I found two very strange problems in MySQL database.

My MySQL database version is **5.6**.

**Problem 1:**

I have simple store procedure for update column value:

Store procedure is as below:

```
drop PROCEDURE if exists mysql_TestProc;

CREATE PROCEDURE mysql_TestProc(Finaltable VARCHAR(1024),ColTOProcess VARCHAR(1024)
,strFind TEXT,strReplace TEXT)

Label1:BEGIN   


 DECLARE code VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '00000' ;

 -- Exception Handler

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION   
    BEGIN            

 GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 
        code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE;

    END;             

      -- generate dynamic Query 
      SET @s:=CONCAT('UPDATE ',FinalTable,' SET 
',ColTOProcess,'=REPLACE(',ColTOProcess,',\'',strFind,'\',\'',strReplace ,'\');');             
      PREPARE stmt from @s;     
      EXECUTE stmt;

      -- If any exeption during query execution then Exception Handler will 
      -- assign error code to "code" variable 
      -- else "code" variable will have default value.

      IF code != '00000' THEN       
      -- Error found..
      select code ;      
      LEAVE Label1;  
      END IF;  
END;


call mysql_TestProc("AnyTableName","ColumnName","Find Value","Replace Value").
```

If you call above store procedure with appropriate parameters it will 
successfully update value.

But in my database It successfully update value with error code "**42S22**".

I changed machine then everything works fine.

So This strange behavior is only with my machine and my database("_temp").

**Problem 2:**

I have simple procedure as below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysql_PrepareLogTable;

CREATE PROCEDURE mysql_PrepareLogTable(LogTable VARCHAR(1024),code TEXT,comment TEXT,category VARCHAR(1024),timestamp DATETIME,duration VARCHAR(100),rows INT,msg TEXT)
BEGIN   
SET code=CONCAT(comment,' \n ',code);  
 SET @tempprepare=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',LogTable,' VALUES ("',code,'","',category,'","',timestamp,'","',duration,'",',rows,',','"',msg,'")');   
 PREPARE stmt from @tempprepare;     
EXECUTE stmt;  
END;
```

I can compile above store procedure script all my mysql databases except one database("test2").
Only in database "test2",  I am not able to compile above store procedure script.
Even I drop the store procedure and then try to execute the script but still It failed to compile script in database "test2".

I am using Toad 6 and mysql workbench 6.0.

So, anyone has any idea about these two problems.

Thank You,
Ronak

Comment: what error message do you get in Case 2?

Comment: syntax error.@golimar

Comment: Looks like a delimiter problem, check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Oh ok let me check an I will let you know result and thnx. :) @golimar